# Hacky way to augment multichannel images in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I need to augment multichannel images and would like to use ImageDataGenerator
Unfortunately, it supports 1,3 and 4 channel images only and I need much more. Would it be OK to directly edit site-packages/Keras/preprocessing/image.py adding necessary number of channels?

```
    if x.shape[self.channel_axis] not in {1, 3, 4, XXX}:
        raise ValueError(
            'Expected input to be images (as Numpy array) '
            'following the dimension ordering convention "' + self.dim_ordering + '" '
            '(channels on axis ' + str(self.channel_axis) + '), i.e. expected '
            'either 1, 3 or 4 channels on axis ' + str(self.channel_axis) + '. '
            'However, it was passed an array with shape ' + str(x.shape) +
            ' (' + str(x.shape[self.channel_axis]) + ' channels).')
```

where XXX - is a number of channels that I need. Would this break anything?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried that anyway and it seems to work without too many side effects. I didn't explore every possible problem, though. So if you have multichannel data (like satellite imagery, etc) you can try this hack. There are couple of places where you need to augment the augmentation code :)

Comment: How did you augment the data? Did you use ImageDataGenerator or did you write your own custom function for this? I have the same problem as you did, I need to augment volumetric data (MRI images). I mean, did you write any other custom function apart from the hack that you have done?

Comment: Hi, Raghuram! No, I used ImageDataGenerator alone.

Comment: After editing and running the file, I get an error saying File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 446, in flow_from_directory
    follow_links=follow_links)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 777, in __init__
    for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Any idea about this?

Comment: Hi Raghuram, are you trying to use flow_from_directory or similar? I didn't use it and used only ImageDataGenerator for in-memory stacks.

Comment: Oh, alright. I think that clears things up a bit. Thanks for the info, Dennis :)